# Enable Auto Sign In with Google Smart Lock on Android

Tags: android, google-signin, google-smartlockpasswords

On the package `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials` we have a function called `disableAutoSignIn()` that will disable auto sign in for the current app so that the popup with the account(s) saved will always be shown to the user, right?

If yes, why don't we have a similar function to enable it again? Any way of doing this?

Comment: What's the use case for re-enabling auto sign-in?

Comment: @Steven Soneff basically I want to force the app to show the popup (even when we have only one saved credential) but in other scenarios/screens I don't (I prefer auto sign in if possible)